# Split the dataframe into subset dataframes and naming them on-the-fly (for loop)

Tags: r, for-loop, split

I have 9880 records in a data frame, I am trying to split it into 9 groups of 1000 each and the last group will have 880 records and also name them accordingly. I used for-loop for 1-9 groups but manually for the last 880 records, but i am sure there are better ways to achieve this,

```
library(sqldf)
for (i in 0:8)
{
assign(paste("test",i,sep="_"),as.data.frame(final_9880[((1000*i)+1):(1000*(i+1)),   (1:53)]))
}
test_9<- num_final_9880[9001:9880,1:53]
```

also am unable to append all the parts in one for-loop!

```
#append all parts
all_9880<-rbind(test_0,test_1,test_2,test_3,test_4,test_5,test_6,test_7,test_8,test_9)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Let me get this straight. You're trying to move per 1000 observations to an individual object (test_1, test_2...) and then at the end, rbind this together? Wouldn't you get the same object as when you started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small variation on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7060331/986817) solution

```
ls <- split(final_9880, rep(0:9, each = 1000, length.out = 9880))  # edited to Roman's suggestion
for(i in 1:10) assign(paste("test",i,sep="_"), ls[[i]])
```

Your command for binding should work.

**Edit**

If you have many dataframes you can use a parse-eval combo. I use the package `gsubfn` for readability.

```
library(gsubfn)
nms <- paste("test", 1:10, sep="_", collapse=",")
eval(fn$parse(text='do.call(rbind, list($nms))'))
```

How does this work? First I create a string containing the comma-separated list of the dataframes

```
> paste("test", 1:10, sep="_", collapse=",")
[1] "test_1,test_2,test_3,test_4,test_5,test_6,test_7,test_8,test_9,test_10"
```

Then I use this string to construct the list

```
list(test_1,test_2,test_3,test_4,test_5,test_6,test_7,test_8,test_9,test_10)
```

using `parse` and `eval` with string interpolation.

```
eval(fn$parse(text='list($nms)'))
```

String interpolation is implemented via the `fn$` prefix of `parse`, its effect is to intercept and substitute `$nms` with the string contained in the variable `nms`. Parsing and evaluating the string `"list($mns)"` creates the list needed. In the solution the `rbind` is included in the parse-eval combo.

*EDIT 2*

You can collect all variables with a certain pattern, put them in a list and bind them by rows.

```
do.call("rbind", sapply(ls(pattern = "test_"), get, simplify = FALSE))
```

`ls` finds all variables with a pattern "test_"

`sapply` retrieves all those variables and stores them in a list

`do.call` flattens the list row-wise.

Comment: Thanks! i know the rbind works..but suppose the file is of million records and i am splitting it into 100 parts...it will be tiresome to rbind individually, is there any way to append them using for loop or something?

Comment: Why do you need to bind them anyway? Surely the it will return the original data?

Comment: mnel: acutally am treating the data splits and then appending it
@RYogi: yup, this did it. thanks alot ppl :)

Comment: @RYogi: i really want to vote up your answer but #reps restricting me :) thanks for the backend edit

Comment: zodiac: no worries, I am glad you gave me an excuse to pull out `eval(fn$parse())`.

Comment: You could do `rep(0:9, each = 1000, length.out = 9880)`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, interesting. How can you use that in this context? `list(ls(pattern = "test_"))` returns a list of strings, the names of the variables matching the pattern.

Comment: @RYogi, I would approach this like so:

`test_1 <- runif(10);
test_2 <- runif(10);
test_3 <- runif(10);
do.call("rbind", sapply(ls(pattern = "test_"), get, simplify = FALSE))`

Answer (score 2):

No for loop required -- use `split`

```
data <- data.frame(a = 1:9880, b = sample(letters, 9880, replace = TRUE))

splitter <- (data$a-1) %/% 1000

.list <- split(data, splitter)

lapply(0:9, function(i){
  assign(paste('test',i,sep='_'), .list[[(i+1)]], envir = .GlobalEnv)
  return(invisible())
})

all_9880<-rbind(test_0,test_1,test_2,test_3,test_4,test_5,test_6,test_7,test_8,test_9)

identical(all_9880,data)
## [1] TRUE
```