# Split data frame into rows of fixed size

Tags: r, split, dataframe, plyr

I have a bunch of data frames with varying degrees of length, ranging from approx. 15,000 to 500,000.  For each of these data frames, I would like to split them up into smaller data frames each with 300 rows which I would do further processing on.  How can I do this?

This ([Split up a dataframe by number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060272/split-up-a-dataframe-in-r-by-number-of-rows)) provides a partial answer, but it doesn't work because not all my data frames have length that are multiples of 300.

I would greatly appreciate it if a plyr and non-plyr solution can both be provided.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't understand why a plyr solution is needed. `split` works perfectly well and even hadley himself didn't suggest a plyr/reshape2 solution when he looked at the earlier question:

```
split(dfrm, (0:nrow(dfrm) %/% 300)  # modulo division
```

Does produce a warning but since you were expecting a non-evenly divisible result you should ignore it.

Comment: (Terrible) Haiku: "Where is the `plyr`? / It is not needed this time / `split`, do not `apply`!"

Comment: OMG. I'm being stalked.

Comment: You started this! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following may help

```
numBreaks <- nrow(DAT)%/%300 + 1
for( i in seq(numBreaks)){
  smallDAT <- DAT[((i-1)*300+1):(min(nrow(DAT), i*300)), ]
.....
}
```