# R: Splitting data frame into equal size groups

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a `data.frame` that has 9 columns and over 16k rows. I need to split the data.frame into 50 groups by one column that is in ascending order (Subj_Avg_Home). The groups should be around equal size.

I searched for an answer in the posts

My data frame looks something like this.

```
head(thesisdata)
 ID          Home_Score Away_Score Subj_Avg_Home 
48550            4            2       0.0181413635731533           
30965            4            1       0.016167700385985           
40501            5            1       0.0185671994247871           
41771            3            5       0.0186986545666144          
42138            3            4       0.01900475916696            
42975            4            7       0.0202611448135552
43724            1            1       0.0204169805144118
47592            4            3       0.020769733472299
47201            3            4       0.0207922542122643
```

If I would split this sample into three groups I would like to have three groups like below

```
 head(group 1)
 ID          Home_Score Away_Score Subj_Avg_Home 
48550            4            2       0.0181413635731533           
30965            4            1       0.016167700385985           
40501            5            1       0.0185671994247871 

head(group 2)         
41771            3            5       0.0186986545666144          
42138            3            4       0.01900475916696            
42975            4            7       0.0202611448135552

head(group 3)
43724            1            1       0.0204169805144118
47592            4            3       0.020769733472299
47201            3            4       0.0207922542122643
```

I am sorry if my formatting is not optimal!

Comment: As suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139708/split-data-frame-into-rows-of-fixed-size), you could try `split(df, (0:nrow(df) %/% 3)) `

Comment: That doesn't group it by quantiles though

Comment: I was just about to post this answer:  quantile_generator <- function(input_vector, quantiles = 4) {
  tiles <- quantile(input_vector, probs = seq(0,1,1/quantiles))
  temp <- rep(NA,length(input_vector))
  for (i in 2:length(tiles)){
    temp[input_vector <= tiles[i] & is.na(temp)] <- i
  }
  return(temp)
}

tempvec <- runif(100,0,1)
df <- data.frame(v1= tempvec, v2= quantile_generator(tempvec, 4))
split(df, df$v2)