# Subsetting using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a wide dataset, I want to subset it by grouping every 50 variables and saving those as a separate dataframe to enable further analysis.

```
df1 <- df[,1:50]
df2 <- df[,51:100] etc
```

Is there a way of combining purrr and dplyr to loop over the entire data set to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split up a dataframe by number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060272/split-up-a-dataframe-by-number-of-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` by creating a grouping variable with `%/%` into a `list` of 'data.frame's.

```
lst <-  split.default(df, (seq_len(ncol(df))-1) %/%50 + 1)
```

It would be better to keep the datasets in the `list` instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment.  But, if we need it, one option is `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(lst, paste0("df", seq_along(lst))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq_len(1200), 10, 120))
```

Comment: `ceiling(sequence(NROW(df))/50)` could also be used as grouping factor for `split`