# Function to select sequential data by row in a dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to use this as a learning exercise. I have a dataset of 343345 rows, and need to geocode the data in ArcGIS, however the full dataset is too large to run properly. I need to break up the data into chunks of 50,000 rows, with the last chunk being a bit smaller.

Currently, I am doing this manually, in individual chunks of 50,000, as seen here

```
gen_gis_test_1_50 = gen_gis[c(1:50000),]
gen_gis_test_51_100 = gen_gis[c(50001:100000),]
```

Then I use `write.csv()` for each new variable I created.

Ive done many of these rote exercises and wanted to see what the best method for writing a function would be. Ideally the function would read the main file, then spit out a new variable for every 50,000 rows. Then id like to write a second function that goes through each of those and writes it as a csv.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: First part of your question seems a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060272/split-up-a-dataframe-by-number-of-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with using the tidyverse there are some neat functions that do these in a short and easy way. You first create a grouping variable (just divide the rownumbers by 50000 and take the modulo). Next you group the dataset using `dplyr`s `group_by` function before you write the data to csv files by using the `group_map` function also from the `dplyr` package.

Using Darren Tsais example (iris datasets splitting to 40 rows each), this would look like this:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  mutate(grp = (row_number() - 1) %/% 40) %>% #create the modulo of the rownumber divided by 40
  group_by(grp) %>%
  group_map(~write.csv(.x, file = paste0("dataset_split_", .y, ".csv")))
```

In the `group_map` function the `~` is used to define the function that will be applied to each group of your dataframe. `.x` is representing the (split) datasets (which are now at most 40 rows long) and `.y` is representing the grouping value (in this case 0-3) so that you have a different filename for each group. The resulting files would be named `dataset_split_0.csv`, `dataset_split_1.csv`, `dataset_split_2.csv` and `dataset_split_3.csv`. In your case just replace `iris` with `gen_gis` and `40` with `50000` and it should work.

Comment: thanks, so tried your example but i get the error "Error in group_by(grp) : object 'grp' not found". I did replace iris and 40 with my specific values too. The error comes after i run the "group_by(grp)..." code

Comment: It's more thoughtful to use `mutate(grp = (row_number() - 1) %/% 40)`. You can check the difference between `table((1:150) %/% 40)` and `table((1:150 - 1) %/% 40)`.

Comment: @DeebaYavrom Oh, right, I forgot a `%>%` after the `group_by`, which is needed so the whole code chunk gets executed as one chain of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Take the built-in dataset `iris` for example, which has 150 rows. Now I want to break up the data into chunks of 40 rows. We know `150 / 40 = 3...30`, so the last chunk will be `iris[121:150, ]`. Then with the following calculation:

```
df <- iris
n <- 40
grp <- (1:nrow(df)-1) %/% n

table(grp)
#  1  2  3  4 
# 40 40 40 30
```

You can get 4 groups. Each group has 40 rows except the last one. Finally, use `split()` to divide data and `Map()` to export each one.

```
df_split <- split(df, grp)
Map(function(x, y){
  write.csv(x, sprintf("gen_gis_%d_%d.csv", y, y + nrow(x) - 1), row.names = F)
}, df_split, (seq_along(df_split)-1) * n + 1)
```

Check your working directory:

[image]