# How to split or apply a function to interspersed groups were each group has a specific chunk size in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with two groups, but they don't have any identifiers. These two groups are interspersed many times but always by the same chunk size. For example, in a dataframe with 100 rows, the first 10 rows belong to group A, the next 6 rows belong to group B, the next 10 belong again to group A, etc. In the snippet below, rows 1 to 10 belong to group A, 11 to 16 belong to group B, 17 to 26 to group A again, and so on.

```
1,0.001284150523134
2,0.002207901328802
3,0.002915323944762
4,0.003469731891528
5,0.003921566996723
6,0.004299059510231
7,0.004616158548743
8,0.004884272348136
9,0.005112133454531
10,0.005309570115060
11,0.004684340208769
12,0.004182199947536
13,0.003777556587011
14,0.003452226985246
15,0.003190805669874
16,0.002980756806210
17,0.003067432902753
18,0.003176181111485
19,0.003286415245384
20,0.003386073280126
21,0.003470669966191
22,0.003541931044310
23,0.003600175259635
24,0.003642340423539
25,0.003669032361358
26,0.003684990806505
...
```

How can I split this dataframe in two? Or better, how can I apply a calculation/function to each of these chunks, one at a time?

Comment: Probably duplicating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060272/split-up-a-dataframe-by-number-of-rows

Comment: I already tried it, but my two groups have DIFFERENT chunk sizes and are INTERSPERSED.

Comment: Maybe something like: `dat <- data.frame(id=c(1:32)); cumsum(rep(c(1:10,1:6), length.out=nrow(dat))==1)` ? If you can provide example data that is representative of your real data, then the corner cases could be accounted for.

Comment: and then store ^ as a column/factor/identifier then use split() and then use one of the applys (lapply, mclapply, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a counter using some sequences:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1:32))

dat$grp <- rep(rep(c(1,2), c(10,6)), length.out=nrow(dat))
dat
#   id grp
#1   1   1
 ...
#10 10   1
#11 11   2
 ...
#16 16   2
#17 17   1
 ...
#26 26   1
#27 27   2
 ...
#32 32   2
```

Then you can use whatever function you want within each group via `aggregate` / `by`/`dplyr::group_by`/data.table's `by=` etc.

Comment: Just an addendum in case anyone needs it, to identify each chunk with a unique number, replace `c(10,6)` with `rep(c(10,6), times=2)`.