# Splitting data in R in order

Tags: r

Here is splitting a range into 3 sections in R:

```
> a=1:35
> split(a, 1:3)
$`1`
 [1]  1  4  7 10 13 16 19 22 25 28 31 34

$`2`
 [1]  2  5  8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35

$`3`
 [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33
```

However, I wanted it split into 1:12, 13:24, 25:35 instead. How do I get it not to re-order?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groupings you passed are 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ... but you actually wanted 1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 3, 3, 3, ..., 3.

```
a = 1:35
groups = c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 12), rep(3, 11))
split(a, groups)
$`1`
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

$`2`
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

$`3`
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  So if I want to split a list of unknown size into groups of 3, I will potentially have to do a lot of calculation? (I realize that is slightly different from the question I asked.)