# Convert a List to a Data Frame after a Split

Tags: r, split, dataframe

The top post of this question helped me equally divide a vector into an even set of chunks:

[Split a vector into chunks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r)

My problem now is that I would like to construct data frames out of the output. Here is the problem in R syntax:

```
d <- rpois(73,5)
solution1 <- split(d, ceiling(seq_along(d)/20))
ERROR <- as.data.frame(solution1)
```

The error that you should see is "arguments imply differing number of rows." I'm especially confused because I thought that the as.data.frame() function could handle this problem, as evident here:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-list-to-a-data-frame-2/

Thanks for all your help!

EDIT 1:

I am close to a solution with this line, however, there are NA values that are being introduced that distort the output that I seek:

```
ldply(solution1,data.frame)
```

ldply is from the plyr package

Comment: i'm confused nevertheless

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? 73 doesn't divide equally except with itself.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the `?split` help page? Did you notice the `unsplit()` function? That sounds like exactly what you're trying to do here.

```
d <- rpois(73,5)
f <- ceiling(seq_along(d)/20) #factor for splitting
solution1 <- split(d, f)
unsplit(solution1 , f)
```

I'm not sure what you expected your data.frame to look like, but the error message you got was because `as.data.frame()` was trying to create a new column in your data.frame for each item in `solution1`. And since each of those vectors in the list has a different number of elements, you cannot make a `data.frame` from that. A `data.frame` requires that every column has the same number of rows.

Comment: Very good solution for splitting data frame. I need additional help on this, I want the 4 lists got created in this process to be 4 separate data frames so that I can use them further. I want them locally available. Please help, use the above as an example.