# Split a vector into unequal chunks in R

Tags: r, split

I have the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r), except I want to specify the variable split lengths with another vector. So, something like this:

```
example.data<-paste("ex",1:10,sep="")
example.data
 [1] "ex1"  "ex2"  "ex3"  "ex4"  "ex5"  "ex6"  "ex7"  "ex8"  "ex9"  "ex10"
split.lens <- c(4,2,1,3)
```

should give me the following list:

```
result.list
[[1]]
[1] "ex1" "ex2" "ex3" "ex4"

[[2]]
[1] "ex5" "ex6"

[[3]]
[1] "ex7"

[[4]]
[1] "ex8"  "ex9"  "ex10"
```

I can't figure out the best way to do this with `split`. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
split(example.data, rep(1:4, c(4,2,1,3)))
```

Comment: Thank you. So simple...and yet: R. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You are welcome! It would be nice if you accepted the answer if it was useful for you...

Comment: had to wait for the 6 minute time limit :)

Comment: Less hard coded (more programmatic) would be `rep(seq_along(split.lens), split.lens)` if we assume they had already created the `split.lens` object. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

I have added a more general method to the dev version of [**qdapTools**](https://github.com/trinker/qdapTools) to split various data types at specific locations.  Here is that approach:

```
## install qdapTools
devtools::install_github("trinker/qdapTools")

library(qdapTools)
loc_split(example.data, head(cumsum(split.lens) + 1, -1))

## [[1]]
## [1] "ex1" "ex2" "ex3" "ex4"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "ex5" "ex6"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "ex7"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "ex8"  "ex9"  "ex10"
```

The function essentially wraps code similar to @RStudent's answer when applied to vectors.

Comment: More to check in qdap and qdapTools. So many functions to learn. This is a nice function. :)