# Create a new list by recombining information from previous lists

Tags: r, list

I have two lists (Phase and Rate in the example). What I need to do is to create a new list with two nested lists where the elements of the second one (Rate) are grouped by the levels of the first one (Phase).
It might be a very basic question but I could not come up with a solution.

```
Phase <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
Rate <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 9)

list(A = c(1, 2, 3, 2), B = c(6, 2, 9))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This question is general and should have a duplicate somewhere, but couldn't find one hence posting an answer.

Comment: @RonakShah let me find for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388706/split-a-vector-into-unequal-chunks-in-r

Comment: @Wen Thanks but I don't think so, this question is more simpler than that. However, if you think it answers the OP's question please go ahead and mark it as dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `split`, to split `Rate` based on `Phase` and it returns a `list`

```
split(Rate, Phase)

#$A
#[1] 1 2 3 2

#$B
#[1] 6 2 9
```