# How do i change split to a horizontal split in R?

Tags: r, vector, split

I have the vector

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
```

that I split in the following manner:

```
split(x, 1:2)
```

It comes out as (a, c, e) and (b, d, f), yet I want (a, b, c) and (d, e, f). Any way of changing it to a horizontal split rather than a vertical one?

Comment: Have a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r) that covers numerous ways of splitting vectors.

Comment: [This function](https://gist.github.com/sckott/4632735) also could be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
split(x, rep(1:2, each = length(x)/2))
```

which gives:

```
$`1`
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$`2`
[1] "D" "E" "F"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `gl`

```
split(x, as.numeric(gl(length(x), 3, length(x))))
```