# Combining elements in a string vector with defined element size and accounting for not event sizes

Tags: r, string, vector, paste

Given is vector:

```
vec <- c(LETTERS[1:10])
```

I would like to be able to combine it in a following manner:

```
resA <- c("AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ")
resB <- c("ABCDEF","GHIJ")
```

where elements of the vector `vec` are merged together according to the desired size of a new element constituting the resulting vector. This is **2** in case of `resA` and **5** in case of `resB`.

### Desired solution characteristics

- The solution should allow for flexibility with respect to the element sizes, i.e. I may want to have vectors with elements of size 2 or 20
- *There may be not enough elements in the vector to match the desired chunk size,* in that case last element should be shortened accordingly (as shown)
- This is shouldn't make a difference but the solution should work on *words* as well

---

## Attempts

Initially, I was thinking of using something on the lines:

```
c(
  paste0(vec[1:2], collapse = ""),
  paste0(vec[3:4], collapse = ""),
  paste0(vec[5:6], collapse = "")
  # ...
)
```

but this would have to be adapted to jump through the remaining pairs/bigger groups of the `vec` and handle last group which often would be of a smaller size.

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r) helpful.

Comment: @jazzurro  I'll have a look, what I need is that but other round, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec <- c(LETTERS[1:10])

f1 <- function(x, n){
  f <- function(x) paste0(x, collapse = '')
  regmatches(f(x), gregexpr(f(rep('.', n)), f(x)))[[1]]
}

f1(vec, 2)
# [1] "AB" "CD" "EF" "GH" "IJ"
```

or

```
f2 <- function(x, n)
  apply(matrix(x, nrow = n), 2, paste0, collapse = '')

f2(vec, 5)
# [1] "ABCDE" "FGHIJ"
```

or

```
f3 <- function(x, n) {
  f <- function(x) paste0(x, collapse = '')
  strsplit(gsub(sprintf('(%s)', f(rep('.', n))), '\\1 ', f(x)), '\\s+')[[1]]
}

f3(vec, 4)
# [1] "ABCD" "EFGH" "IJ"
```

I would say the last is best of these since `n` for the others must be a factor or you will get warnings or recycling

edit - more

```
f4 <- function(x, n) {
  f <- function(x) paste0(x, collapse = '')
  Vectorize(substring, USE.NAMES = FALSE)(f(x), which((seq_along(x) %% n) == 1),
                                          which((seq_along(x) %% n) == 0))
}

f4(vec, 2)
# [1] "AB" "CD" "EF" "GH" "IJ"
```

or

```
f5  <- function(x, n)
  mapply(function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ''),
         split(x, c(0, head(cumsum(rep_len(sequence(n), length(x)) %in% n), -1))),
         USE.NAMES = FALSE)

f5(vec, 4)
# [1] "ABCD" "EFGH" "IJ"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I came up with. Using Harlan's idea in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r), you can split the vector in different number of chunks. You also want to use your `paste0()` idea in `lapply()` here. Finally, you unlist a list.

```
unlist(lapply(split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec)/2)), function(x){paste0(x, collapse = "")}))

#   1    2    3    4    5 
#"AB" "CD" "EF" "GH" "IJ" 

unlist(lapply(split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec)/5)), function(x){paste0(x, collapse = "")}))

#      1       2 
#"ABCDE" "FGHIJ" 

unlist(lapply(split(vec, ceiling(seq_along(vec)/3)), function(x){paste0(x, collapse = "")}))

#    1     2     3     4 
#"ABC" "DEF" "GHI"   "J"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, working with the original array.
A side note, working with words is not straightforward, since there is at least two ways to understand it: you can either keep each word separately or collapse them first an get individual characters. The next function can deal with both options.

```
vec <- c(LETTERS[1:10])
vec2 <- c("AB","CDE","F","GHIJ")

cuts <- function(x, n, bychar=F) {
    if (bychar) x <- unlist(strsplit(paste0(x, collapse=""), ""))
    ii <- seq_along(x)
    li <- split(ii, ceiling(ii/n))
    return(sapply(li, function(y) paste0(x[y], collapse="")))
}

cuts(vec2,2,F)
#      1       2 
# "ABCDE" "FGHIJ" 

cuts(vec2,2,T)
#    1    2    3    4    5 
# "AB" "CD" "EF" "GH" "IJ"
```