# Discretizing the log of a continuous variable

Tags: r, discretization

I am trying to discretize a continuous variable, cutting it into three levels. I want to do the same thing for the log of the positive continuous variable (in this case, income).

```
require(dplyr)
set.seed(3)
mydata = data.frame(realinc = rexp(10000))

summary(mydata)

new = mydata %>% 
  select(realinc) %>%
  mutate(logrealinc = log(realinc),
         realincTercile = cut(realinc, 3),
         logrealincTercile = cut(logrealinc, 3),
         realincTercileNum = as.numeric(realincTercile),
         logrealincTercileNum = as.numeric(logrealincTercile)) 

new[sample(1:nrow(new), 10),]
```

I would have thought that using `cut()` would produce identical levels for the discretized factors of each of these variables (income and log income), because log is a monotone function. So the two columns on the right here should be equal, but that doesn't seem to happen. What's going on?

```
> new[sample(1:nrow(new), 10),]
       realinc  logrealinc  realincTercile logrealincTercile realincTercileNum logrealincTercileNum
7931 0.2967813 -1.21475972 (-0.00805,2.83]     (-4.43,-1.15]                 1                    2
9036 0.9511824 -0.05004944 (-0.00805,2.83]      (-1.15,2.15]                 1                    3
8204 4.5365676  1.51217069     (2.83,5.66]      (-1.15,2.15]                 2                    3
3136 2.0610693  0.72322490 (-0.00805,2.83]      (-1.15,2.15]                 1                    3
9708 0.9655805 -0.03502581 (-0.00805,2.83]      (-1.15,2.15]                 1                    3
5942 0.9149351 -0.08890215 (-0.00805,2.83]      (-1.15,2.15]                 1                    3
4631 0.6987581 -0.35845064 (-0.00805,2.83]      (-1.15,2.15]                 1                    3
7309 1.9532566  0.66949804 (-0.00805,2.83]      (-1.15,2.15]                 1                    3
7708 0.4220254 -0.86268973 (-0.00805,2.83]      (-1.15,2.15]                 1                    3
2965 1.3690976  0.31415186 (-0.00805,2.83]      (-1.15,2.15]                 1                    3
```

**Edit:** @nicola's comment explains the source of the problem. It seems that in `cut`'s documentation, "equal-length intervals" refers to the length of the interval in the space of the continuous argument. I had originally interpreted "equal-length intervals" as meaning the number of elements assigned to each cut (on the output) would be equal (instead of the input).

Is there a function that does what I'm describing? -- where the number of elements in each output level are equal? Equivalently, where the levels of `newfunc(realinc)` and `newfunc(logrealinc)` are equal?

Comment: `log` is not a linear transformation. Say that `x` is uniformly distributed between 1 and 5. Do you expect that `log(x)` is uniformly distributed between `log(1)` and `log(5)`? In your example, try `hist(new$realinc)` and `hist(new$logrealinc)` to see how they differ. `cut` just cuts the entire range in basically constant intervals; an element can well fall into an interval and its log into another.

Comment: @nicola Thanks, that's helpful. I've updated the question with that in mind.

Comment: You can search for split vector into equal chunks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your levels to be equally populated, take a look at the `quantile` function. Try for instance:

```
x<-cut(new$realinc,quantile(new$realinc,0:3/3))
y<-cut(new$logrealinc,quantile(new$logrealinc,0:3/3))
all(as.integer(x)==as.integer(y),na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
table(x)
#x
#(0.000444,0.396]     (0.396,1.12]      (1.12,8.49] 
#            3333             3333             3333
```