# Load a snippet of code into frames

Tags: r

I have a snippet of code like this:

```
for(i in 1:4000000) {
 #code to do
}
```

I would like to load this for every 10000 until the counter go to 4000000

```
Example:
 for(i in 1:10000) {
     #code to do
    }

 for(i in 10001:20000) {
     #code to do
    }

etc.
```

Is there any simpler way to do it than to have multiple for?

Comment: Relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r

Comment: Like: `lapply(split(1:10, ceiling(seq_along(1:10)/5)), function(i){ someCode })`