# Create an ID variable based on a row sequence

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this sequence of data and I want to create an ID every 3 rows:

```
x <- c ("info","x1","y1","z1","x2","y2","z2")
df  <- read.csv(text = x , strip.white = TRUE)
```

The actual strings doesn't have any logical information that I could create an ID column using mutate + ifelse + grepl . I want to create a new column with a sequential number every 3 rows:

```
id  info
 1    x1
 1    y1
 1    z1
 2    x2
 2    y2
 2    z2
```

Comment: `data.frame(df, id = ceiling(1:nrow(df)/3))`

Comment: Heaps of alternatives here: [Split a vector into chunks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r) (just skip the `split` step...). E.g. the top-voted answer is the same as @d.b's suggestion.

Comment: Also, `df$id <- rep(1:(nrow(df)/3), each = 3)`

Comment: `dplyr::mutate(df, ceiling(row_number() / 3))`

Comment: `(sequence(nrow(df))-1) %/% 3`.

Comment: I just answered the question you just deleted.  Let me know if you still want the information.  You may find it useful.

Comment: In a nutshell, this is what it is `wrd = ['is', 'foo']; pat = fr'\b{"|".join(wrd)}\b'; dfc.col1.str.replace(pat, 'X')`