# How to split a large univariate dataframe into multiple smaller dataframes based on a predefined size value?

Tags: r, python-3.x, vector

I have a univariate data frame:

```
Y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

I would like to split it so that I obtain different data frames for x timesteps. For eg, for the case of 2 timesteps, I'd like:

```
Y[1]=[1,2]
Y[2]=[3,4]
Y[3]=[5,6]
```

and so on.....

I even have python code for the same -

```
dfs = list()
for x in range(0, len(Y), 2):
    df = Y.iloc[x:x+2]
    df.columns= ['one','two']
    dfs.append(df)
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
    print()
```

Comment: I hope this helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r

Comment: variateY <- matrix(Y, ncol = 2, nrow = dim(Y)[1]/2, byrow = TRUE)

Comment: @CarlesSansFuentes 'split' definitely is a good idea, however I want a new dataframe for each split. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Rex, there is an error:Error in matrix(Y, ncol = 2, nrow = dim(Y)[1]/2, byrow = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

Comment: Sorry about that. `y` is a vector so it has only one dimension. Use `matrix(Y, nrow = length(Y)/2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: @Rex, this is perfect !!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help!