# How to group by a fixed number of rows in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(10)
y <- x^2
my.df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

The result is this:

```
> my.df
    x   y
1   3   9
2   8  64
3   4  16
4   7  49
5   6  36
6   1   1
7  10 100
8   9  81
9   2   4
10  5  25
```

What I want is to group the rows by every *n* rows to compute the mean, sum, or whatever on the 5 selected rows. Something like this for *n=5*:

```
my.df %>% group_by(5) %>% summarise(sum = sum(y), mean = mean(y))
```

The expected output would be something like:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     sum   mean
   <dbl>  <dbl>
1    174   34.8
2    211   42.2
```

Of course, the number of rows in the data frame could be 15, 20, 100, whatever. I still want to group the data every *n* rows.

How can I do this?

Comment: Relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `rep` or `gl` to create the grouping variable

```
library(dplyr)
my.df %>% 
    group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 5, n()))) %>% 
    #or with rep
    # group_by(grp = rep(row_number(), length.out = n(), each = 5)) 
    summarise(sum = sum(y), mean = mean(y))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#    grp   sum  mean
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1   174  34.8
#2     2   211  42.2
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option could be:

```
my.df %>%
 group_by(x = ceiling(row_number()/5)) %>%
 summarise_all(list(sum = sum, mean = mean))

      x   sum  mean
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   174  34.8
2     2   211  42.2
```