# wrapping wide table in rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable

I have a really wide table (300+ columns) and would like to display it by wrapping the columns. In the example I will just use 100 columns.

What I have in mind is repetitively using kable to display the subset of the table:

```
library(kableExtra)
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300, 10, 1), ncol = 100))

kable(data[, 1:5], 'latex', booktabs = T) 
kable(data[, 6:10], 'latex', booktabs = T) 
kable(data[, 11:15], 'latex', booktabs = T)
```

But this is apparently tedious... I know there are scaling down options but since I have so many columns, it won't be possible.

Is there any parameter I can twist in kable to make it happen?

---

Updated:
@jay.sf 's answer seems working well, but it didn't yield the same result here. Instead I got some plain code - could you please have a second look and let me know where can I improve? Thanks!

[image: results]

my `sessionInfo()` is: `R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)` with `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` of `1.19.2.1`.

Comment: To get pure LaTeX code we have to use `cat`, `sapply` gave a funny output we therefore apply a `for` loop, see my edits, should work fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is actually trickier than I thought at first glance. I used some `tidyverse` functions, specifically `dplyr::select` to get columns and `purrr::map` to move along groups of column indices.

My thinking with this was to make a list of vectors of column indices to choose, such that the first list item is `1:20`, the second is `21:40`, and so on, in order to break the data into 20 tables of 5 columns each (the number you use can be a different factor of `ncol(data)`). I underestimated the work to do that, but got ideas from [an old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3318333/5325862) to rep the numbers 1 to 20 along the number of columns, sort it, and use that as the grouping then to split the columns.

Then each of those vectors becomes the column indices in `select`. The resulting list of data frames each gets passed to `knitr::kable` and `kableExtra::kable_styling`. Leaving things off there would get `map`'s default of printing names as well, which isn't ideal, so I added a call to `purrr::walk` to print them neatly.

Note also that making the `kable`'d tables this way meant putting `results="asis"` in the chunk options.

````
---
title: "knitr chunked"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300, 10, 1), ncol = 100))
```

```{r results='asis'}
split(1:ncol(data), sort(rep_len(1:20, ncol(data)))) %>%
  map(~select(data, .)) %>%
  map(kable, booktabs = T) %>%
  map(kable_styling) %>%
  walk(print)
```
````

Top of the PDF output:

[image: pdf]

Comment: Just want to note that I'd originally broken this into 15 tables of 7 columns just because that was a size where the tables fit fairly neatly in the PDF pages, but decided to change to 20 tables of 5 columns each to better fit what you'd described. Both code and output are updated to match that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a matrix containing your columns numbers and give it into a for loop with the `cat` function inside.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300, 10, 1), ncol=100))

m <- matrix(1:ncol(dat), 5)

for (i in 1:ncol(m)) {
 cat(kable(dat[, m[, i]], 'latex', booktabs=TRUE), "\\newline")
}
```
````

***Result***

[image]

Comment: Hi jay, thank you for your response. It is weird that I copied and pasted your code but didn't yield the same results in my pdf file. It did not displayed in the form of kable tables but basically plain codes. I updated the screenshot in my question description.

Comment: Weird, @RachelZhang, this is exactly what happens to me when I don't have specified option `results="asis"` of the chunk in which I run the code ([Ref.](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf)), could you check that? Otherwise, could you post your `sessionInfo()`, your `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`, and which LaTeX distribution & version you have installed?