# Create groups with a minimum number of elements

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say we have the following dataframe, which is the result of a previous `dplyr::sumarise()` call:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 n = c(8, 7, 3, 3, 1))
```

Here `df$x` is a value which we later want to group over and `df$n` states how many items in the original table had the given `df$x`.

However, there are currently too many groups of `df$x`, such that the higher values have very low `$n`'s, so I want to collapse groups into "supergroups", such that each contains a total `$n` of at least 4.

I've found many similar questions on SO ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3318333/2175231) being the most cited), but none quite like this.

The best solution I've found isn't very elegant, but works:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

mySplit <- function(x, n) {
  a <- seq(n)

  count <- 0
  j <- 1
  for(i in rev(x)) {
    a[i] <- j
    count <- count + n[i]
    if (count >= 4) {
      j <- j + 1
      count <- 0
    }
  }

  return(a)
}

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 n = c(8, 7, 3, 3, 1))

df %>%
  mutate(
    g = mySplit(x, n)
  ) %>%
  group_by(
    desc(g)
  ) %>%
  summarise(
    x = x[1]
    , n = sum(n)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   `desc(g)`     x     n
#>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        -3     1     8
#> 2        -2     2    10
#> 3        -1     4     4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

From that output, we can see that it merged `$x %in% (2, 3)` and `$x %in% (4, 5)`, such that no group has less than 4 items.

However, this isn't a very good solution for many reasons:

- As already stated, it's inelegant
- It's greedy. This is acceptable since I've made it go from back to front; the latter values of `$x` will almost always have the lower `$n`s, so the risk of having poor grouping is reduced.
- It's non-optimal. The best split would arguably have been to leave groups `$x = 1, 2, (3, 4, 5)`, which would have created supergroups of almost equal size (8, 7 and 7).

So, is there a better way to do this I'm unaware of?

This is basically a "rolling sum" function which resets the sum whenever a value is crossed and instead returns the number of "previous resets" (though an optimal solution as stated above would need something much more complex). However, I can't figure out how to actually code that.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cumsumbinning` from `MESS`. For this case, you need [`cutwhenpassed=TRUE`](https://github.com/ekstroem/MESS/issues/4) which is not available on CRAN yet but you can install it from github.

```
devtools::install_github("ekstroem/MESS")
```

`cumsumbinning` basically creates groups until cumulative sum passes a threshold.

```
MESS::cumsumbinning(df$n, 4, cutwhenpassed = TRUE)
#[1] 1 2 3 3 4
```

So here, we can use it as :

```
library(dplyr)
threshold <- 4

df %>%
  group_by(g = MESS::cumsumbinning(n, threshold, cutwhenpassed = TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(x = first(x), n = sum(n))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      g     x     n
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     8
#2     2     2     7
#3     3     3     6
#4     4     5     1
```