# How to quickly form groups (quartiles, deciles, etc) by ordering column(s) in a data frame

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I see a lot of questions and answers re `order` and `sort`. Is there anything that sorts vectors or data frames into groupings (like quartiles or deciles)? I have a "manual" solution, but there's likely a better solution that has been group-tested.

Here's my attempt:

```
temp <- data.frame(name=letters[1:12], value=rnorm(12), quartile=rep(NA, 12))
temp
#    name       value quartile
# 1     a  2.55118169       NA
# 2     b  0.79755259       NA
# 3     c  0.16918905       NA
# 4     d  1.73359245       NA
# 5     e  0.41027113       NA
# 6     f  0.73012966       NA
# 7     g -1.35901658       NA
# 8     h -0.80591167       NA
# 9     i  0.48966739       NA
# 10    j  0.88856758       NA
# 11    k  0.05146856       NA
# 12    l -0.12310229       NA
temp.sorted <- temp[order(temp$value), ]
temp.sorted$quartile <- rep(1:4, each=12/4)
temp <- temp.sorted[order(as.numeric(rownames(temp.sorted))), ]
temp
#    name       value quartile
# 1     a  2.55118169        4
# 2     b  0.79755259        3
# 3     c  0.16918905        2
# 4     d  1.73359245        4
# 5     e  0.41027113        2
# 6     f  0.73012966        3
# 7     g -1.35901658        1
# 8     h -0.80591167        1
# 9     i  0.48966739        3
# 10    j  0.88856758        4
# 11    k  0.05146856        2
# 12    l -0.12310229        1
```

Is there a better (cleaner/faster/one-line) approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The method I use is one of these or `Hmisc::cut2(value, g=4)`:

```
temp$quartile <- with(temp, cut(value, 
                                breaks=quantile(value, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.25), na.rm=TRUE), 
                                include.lowest=TRUE))
```

An alternate might be:

```
temp$quartile <- with(temp, factor(
                            findInterval( val, c(-Inf,
                               quantile(val, probs=c(0.25, .5, .75)), Inf) , na.rm=TRUE), 
                            labels=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
      ))
```

The first one has the side-effect of labeling the quartiles with the values, which I consider a "good thing", but if it were not "good for you", or the valid problems raised in the comments were a concern you could go with version 2. You can use `labels=` in `cut`, or  you could add this line to your code:

```
temp$quartile <- factor(temp$quartile, levels=c("1","2","3","4") )
```

Or even quicker but slightly more obscure in how it works, although it is no longer a factor, but rather a numeric vector:

```
temp$quartile <- as.numeric(temp$quartile)
```

Comment: `cut()` has argument `labels` which can be used so you don't need the `factor()` line - just add `labels = 1:4` in the `cut()` call of your first line.

Comment: The Hmisc package also has a cut2 function with a "m" argument that cuts into "m" (roughly)  equal sections.

Comment: I'd like to add that the error: _'breaks' are not unique_ might occur, if you calculate quantiles for a time series with some duplicates, because e.g. the lowest quantile (0%) might be equal to the next higher one (10%). `findInterval` as used above seems to be better in this case

Comment: @42- could you please suggest the same for deciles and data with NAs.

Comment: for deciles use `probs=c((0:9)/10), Inf)` using findInterval or `probs=seq(0,1, by=0.1))` for cut. An important difference in those two functions is that by default intervals are closed on the left for `findInterval` and closed on the right for `cut`. Good point about NA's; Like sum or main or max, should probably add na.rm=TRUE for `quantile`.

Comment: The bit about `include.lowest` should be in the body of your answer; flagging the comment for deletion :)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think it's totally bizarre to nominate a useful comment for deletion. I'll pay attention to what the moderators do with amused interest. If you felt so strongly about the issue,  think the sensible thing to have done was to do an edit on my answer.

Comment: I disagree -- comments are meant to be ephemeral. any useful content should be incorporated in the answer itself -- especially when that comment is by the author his/herself

Comment: "The first one has the side-effect of labeling the quartiles with the values" I guess one can use something like `as.numeric()` but I am not 100% sure about the order of assignment and correspondence to (e.g.) 1 to first decile, etc.

Answer (score 127):

There's a handy `ntile` function in package `dplyr`. It's flexible in the sense that you can very easily define the number of *tiles or "bins" you want to create.

Load the package (install first if you haven't) and add the quartile column:

```
library(dplyr)
temp$quartile <- ntile(temp$value, 4)
```

Or, if you want to use dplyr syntax:

```
temp <- temp %>% mutate(quartile = ntile(value, 4))
```

Result in both cases is:

```
temp
#   name       value quartile
#1     a -0.56047565        1
#2     b -0.23017749        2
#3     c  1.55870831        4
#4     d  0.07050839        2
#5     e  0.12928774        3
#6     f  1.71506499        4
#7     g  0.46091621        3
#8     h -1.26506123        1
#9     i -0.68685285        1
#10    j -0.44566197        2
#11    k  1.22408180        4
#12    l  0.35981383        3
```

#### data:

Note that you don't need to create the "quartile" column in advance and use `set.seed` to make the randomization reproducible:

```
set.seed(123)
temp <- data.frame(name=letters[1:12], value=rnorm(12))
```

Comment: Good alternative, but your answer is missing information on the breakpoints used by `ntile` (include lowest, highest, ties)

Comment: That should fix the problem of the endpoints, or? 

`temp <- temp %>% mutate(quartile = cut(x = ntile(value, 100), breaks = seq(25,100,25)
                        , include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE
                        , labels = FALSE))`

Answer (score 29):

I'll add the `data.table` version for anyone else Googling it (i.e., @BondedDust's solution translated to `data.table` and pared down a tad):

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)
temp[ , quartile := cut(value,
                        breaks = quantile(value, probs = 0:4/4),
                        labels = 1:4, right = FALSE)]
```

Which is much better (cleaner, [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow)) than what I had been doing:

```r
temp[ , quartile := 
        as.factor(ifelse(value < quantile(value, .25), 1,
                         ifelse(value < quantile(value, .5), 2,
                                ifelse(value < quantile(value, .75), 3, 4))]
```

Note, however, that this approach requires the quantiles to be distinct,  e.g. it will fail on `rep(0:1, c(100, 1))`; what to do in this case is open ended so I leave it up to you.

Comment: The data.table version is the fastest method, by the way. Thanks @MichaelChirico.

Comment: I think `right = F` is incorrect here. Not only is the maximum value not grouped but say your data is 1:21, the median is 11 but gets grouped into the .75-group.

Answer (score 14):

Adapting `dplyr::ntile` to take advantage of `data.table` optimizations provides a faster solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)
temp[order(value) , quartile := floor( 1 + 4 * (.I-1) / .N)]
```

Probably doesn't qualify as cleaner, but it's faster and one-line.

### Timing on bigger data set

Comparing this solution to `ntile` and `cut` for `data.table` as proposed by @docendo_discimus and @MichaelChirico.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

n <- 1e6
temp <- data.frame(name=sample(letters, size=n, replace=TRUE), value=rnorm(n))
setDT(temp)

microbenchmark(
    "ntile" = temp[, quartile_ntile := ntile(value, 4)],
    "cut" = temp[, quartile_cut := cut(value,
                                       breaks = quantile(value, probs = seq(0, 1, by=1/4)),
                                       labels = 1:4, right=FALSE)],
    "dt_ntile" = temp[order(value), quartile_ntile_dt := floor( 1 + 4 * (.I-1)/.N)]
)
```

Gives:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    ntile 608.1126 647.4994 670.3160 686.5103 691.4846 712.4267   100
      cut 369.5391 373.3457 375.0913 374.3107 376.5512 385.8142   100
 dt_ntile 117.5736 119.5802 124.5397 120.5043 124.5902 145.7894   100
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `quantile()` function, but you need to handle rounding/precision when using `cut()`. So

```
set.seed(123)
temp <- data.frame(name=letters[1:12], value=rnorm(12), quartile=rep(NA, 12))
brks <- with(temp, quantile(value, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)))
temp <- within(temp, quartile <- cut(value, breaks = brks, labels = 1:4, 
                                     include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Giving:

```
> head(temp)
  name       value quartile
1    a -0.56047565        1
2    b -0.23017749        2
3    c  1.55870831        4
4    d  0.07050839        2
5    e  0.12928774        3
6    f  1.71506499        4
```

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for being a bit late to the party. I wanted to add my one liner using `cut2` as I didn't know max/min for my data and wanted the groups to be identically large. I read about cut2 in an issue which was marked as duplicate (link below).

```
library(Hmisc)   #For cut2
set.seed(123)    #To keep answers below identical to my random run

temp <- data.frame(name=letters[1:12], value=rnorm(12), quartile=rep(NA, 12))

temp$quartile <- as.numeric(cut2(temp$value, g=4))   #as.numeric to number the factors
temp$quartileBounds <- cut2(temp$value, g=4)

temp
```

Result:

```
> temp
   name       value quartile  quartileBounds
1     a -0.56047565        1 [-1.265,-0.446)
2     b -0.23017749        2 [-0.446, 0.129)
3     c  1.55870831        4 [ 1.224, 1.715]
4     d  0.07050839        2 [-0.446, 0.129)
5     e  0.12928774        3 [ 0.129, 1.224)
6     f  1.71506499        4 [ 1.224, 1.715]
7     g  0.46091621        3 [ 0.129, 1.224)
8     h -1.26506123        1 [-1.265,-0.446)
9     i -0.68685285        1 [-1.265,-0.446)
10    j -0.44566197        2 [-0.446, 0.129)
11    k  1.22408180        4 [ 1.224, 1.715]
12    l  0.35981383        3 [ 0.129, 1.224)
```

[Similar issue where I read about cut2 in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273892/r-splitting-dataset-into-quartiles-deciles-what-is-the-right-method?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
temp$quartile <- ceiling(sapply(temp$value,function(x) sum(x-temp$value>=0))/(length(temp$value)/4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function

```r
getQuantileGroupNum <- function(vec, group_num, decreasing=FALSE) {
  if(decreasing) {
    abs(cut(vec, quantile(vec, probs=seq(0, 1, 1 / group_num), type=8, na.rm=TRUE), labels=FALSE, include.lowest=T) - group_num - 1)
  } else {
    cut(vec, quantile(vec, probs=seq(0, 1, 1 / group_num), type=8, na.rm=TRUE), labels=FALSE, include.lowest=T)
  }
}
```

```r
> t1 <- runif(7)
> t1
[1] 0.4336094 0.2842928 0.5578876 0.2678694 0.6495285 0.3706474 0.5976223
> getQuantileGroupNum(t1, 4)
[1] 2 1 3 1 4 2 4
> getQuantileGroupNum(t1, 4, decreasing=T)
[1] 3 4 2 4 1 3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Take care with ntile() if your original values are clustered at some values.  To create equally sized groups, it will allocate rows with the same original value into different groups.  This may not be desirable.

I had a case where scores of individuals were clustered at certain values and it was important that individuals with the same original score were placed in the same group (e.g. allocating students to groups based on test score).  ntile() allocated individuals with the same score to different groups (unfair in this case), but cut() with quantile() does not (but groups are only approximately equal in size).

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)


# awkward data: cannot be fairly and equally divided into quartiles or quintiles
# (similar results are obtained from more realistic cases of clustered values)
example <- data.frame(id = 1:49, x = c(rep(1:7, each=7))) %>%
  mutate(ntileQuartile = ntile(x, 4),
         cutQuartile = cut(x, breaks=quantile(x, seq(0, 1, by=1/4)),
                           include.lowest=T, label=1:4),
         ntileQuintile = ntile(x, 5),
         cutQuintile = cut(x, breaks=quantile(x, seq(0, 1, by=1/5)),
                           include.lowest=T, label=1:5))


# graph: x axis is original score, colour is group allocation
# ntile creates equal groups, but some values of original score are split
# into separate groups.  cut creates different sized groups, but score 
# exactly determines the group.
melt(example, id.vars=c("id", "x"), 
     variable.name = "method", value.name="groupNumber") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, fill=groupNumber)) +
  geom_histogram(colour="black", bins=13) +
  facet_wrap(vars(method))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a version, which seems to be more robust, since I ran into a lot of problems using `quantile()` in the breaks option `cut()` on my dataset.
I am using the `ntile` function of `plyr`, but it also works with `ecdf` as input.

```
temp[, `:=`(quartile = .bincode(x = ntile(value, 100), breaks = seq(0,100,25), right = TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE)
            decile = .bincode(x = ntile(value, 100), breaks = seq(0,100,10), right = TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE)
)]

temp[, `:=`(quartile = .bincode(x = ecdf(value)(value), breaks = seq(0,1,0.25), right = TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE)
            decile = .bincode(x = ecdf(value)(value), breaks = seq(0,1,0.1), right = TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE)
)]
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

There is possibly a quicker way, but I would do:

```
a <- rnorm(100) # Our data
q <- quantile(a) # You can supply your own breaks, see ?quantile

# Define a simple function that checks in which quantile a number falls
getQuant <- function(x)
   {
   for (i in 1:(length(q)-1))
       {
       if (x>=q[i] && x<q[i+1])
          break;
       }
   i
   }

# Apply the function to the data
res <- unlist(lapply(as.matrix(a), getQuant))
```