# Quantiles in Matlab

Tags: matlab, quantile

Would there be a function in matlab, or an easy way, to generate the quantile groups to which each data point belongs to?

Example:

```
x = [4 0.5 3 5 1.2];
q = quantile(x, 3);

ans =

    1.0250    3.0000    4.2500
```

So I would like to see the following:

```
result = [2 1 2 3 1]; % The quantile groups
```

In other words, I am looking for the equivalent of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126326/how-to-quickly-form-groups-quartiles-deciles-etc-by-ordering-columns-in-a) in matlab

Thanks!

Comment: How are you grouping them? For example if `x=[1 1 1 1 1 6];` then `q` would be `[1 1 1]`.

Comment: Please see the thread link in the post.

Comment: How can both `0.5` and `1.2` be in quantile group `1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through all `n` quantiles in a loop and use logical indexing to find the quantile

```
n = 3;
q = quantile(x,n);
y = ones(size(x));
for k=2:n
    y(x>=q(k)) = k;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you define "quantile group", you could use:

1. If "quantile group" means how many values in `q` are less than `x`:

   ```
   result = sum(bsxfun(@gt, x(:).', q(:)));
   ```
2. If "quantile group" means how many values in `q` are less than or equal to `x`:

   ```
   result = sum(bsxfun(@ge, x(:).', q(:)));
   ```
3. If "quantile group" means index of the value in `q` which is closest to each value in `x`:

   ```
   [~, result] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, x(:).', q(:))));
   ```

None of these returns the result given in your example, though: the first gives `[2 0 1 3 1]`, the second `[2 0 2 3 1]`, the third `[3 1 2 3 1]`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I don't understand though how quantile group can take value of 0. Possible quantiles are 1,2,3

Comment: @Mayou If you answer my question above I can perhaps be of more help