# How to compute quantiles on groups

Tags: r

I want to separate by data into quantiles, same as in [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126326/how-to-quickly-form-groups-quartiles-deciles-etc-by-ordering-columns-in-a)

The problem is that I want to do it every day in a time series:

```
set.seed(123)
temp.all <- data.frame(date = c(rep(Sys.Date() - 1, 12), rep(Sys.Date(), 12)), 
    name=letters[c(1:12, 1:12)], value=rnorm(24))
```

At the moment, I'm solving with a for-loop:

```
library(dplyr)
for (d in unique(temp.all$date)) {
    temp = filter(temp.all, date == d)
    temp$quartile <- with(temp, factor(
                        findInterval( val, c(-Inf,
                           quantile(val, probs=c(0.25, .5, .75)), Inf) , na.rm=TRUE), 
                        labels=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
  ))
  # ...and doing rbind on 'temp' to reconstruct temp.all with quartiles
}
```

Any ideas on how to avoid the dreaded for-loop?  Is there maybe a `group_by` way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `group_by` you can just do:

```
library(lubridate)

temp.all = temp.all %>%
    # lubridate::date(date) might be necessary if you have datetimes
    group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(quartile = cut(value, breaks = 4, labels = paste0("Q", 1:4)))
```

`dplyr` also has a function `ntile` which should behave similarly to `cut` and should give the same results.

Comment: The `ntile` function breaks ties arbitrarily, so I'll stick to `cut`.  I take your point:  use `group_by` then `mutate`.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @Uwe, the code works for the example data but would give the incorrect answer with the same day in more than one month. Just `group_by(date)` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness (and to correct a wrong answer), here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp.all)[, quartile := cut(value, breaks = 4L, labels = paste0("Q", 1:4)), by = date]
temp.all
```

> ```
>           date name       value quartile
>  1: 2017-08-28    a -0.56047565       Q1
>  2: 2017-08-28    b -0.23017749       Q2
>  3: 2017-08-28    c  1.55870831       Q4
>  4: 2017-08-28    d  0.07050839       Q2
>  5: 2017-08-28    e  0.12928774       Q2
>  6: 2017-08-28    f  1.71506499       Q4
> ...
> 18: 2017-08-29    f -1.96661716       Q1
> 19: 2017-08-29    g  0.70135590       Q3
> 20: 2017-08-29    h -0.47279141       Q2
> 21: 2017-08-29    i -1.06782371       Q1
> 22: 2017-08-29    j -0.21797491       Q2
> 23: 2017-08-29    k -1.02600445       Q2
> 24: 2017-08-29    l -0.72889123       Q2
>           date name       value quartile
> ```

Note that the results are grouped by `date` as requested by the OP and not by `day(date)` which would aggregate the *day of month*, e.g., January 1st, February 1st, March 1st, etc.

Further note that only one additional column `quartile` is being added to `temp.all` *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole data set in order to save memory and time (which might become relevant when dealing with large data sets).