# How to bin values based on another value

Tags: r

I want to make 10 bins of a factor FRATERNITY.SORORITY by the proportion of people who donated.

I have an aggregate statement to do this and have tried to cross-reference this into a binning loop but couldn't get it to work.

```
   FRATERNITY.SORORITY (as.numeric(Donated) - 1)
1                 None                 0.1554272
2     Alpha Epsilon Pi                 0.6363636
3      Alpha Tau Omega                 0.3125000
4             Combined                 0.4545455
5      Alpha Chi Omega                 0.4117647
6       Alpha Delta Pi                 0.2857143
7    Alpha Gamma Delta                 0.3333333
8      Alpha Gamma Rho                 0.4444444
9    Alpha Kappa Alpha                 0.0000000
10    Alpha Omicron Pi                 0.2469136
11      Alpha Xi Delta                 0.1600000
12       Beta Theta Pi                 0.1250000
13           Chi Omega                 0.2619048
14             Chi Phi                 0.1666667
15   Delta Delta Delta                 0.2467532
16         Delta Gamma                 0.3750000
17   Delta Sigma Theta                 0.0000000
18     Delta Tau Delta                 0.3181818
19       Delta Upsilon                 0.6666667
20          Delta Zeta                 0.3529412
21         Kappa Alpha                 0.4285714
22         Kappa Delta                 0.2083333
23   Kappa Kappa Gamma                 0.2142857
24         Kappa Sigma                 0.3750000
25    Lambda Chi Alpha                 0.3875000
26     Phi Delta Theta                 0.3888889
27     Phi Gamma Delta                 0.3552632
28       Phi Kappa Psi                 0.3333333
29       Phi Kappa Tau                 0.6250000
30              Phi Mu                 0.1481481
31     Phi Sigma Kappa                 0.2727273
32         Pi Beta Phi                 0.2105263
33      Pi Kappa Alpha                 0.3166667
34        Pi Kappa Phi                 0.1000000
35 Sigma Alpha Epsilon                 0.3402062
36           Sigma Chi                 0.4714286
37         Sigma Kappa                 0.2758621
38            Sigma Nu                 0.2857143
39   Sigma Phi Epsilon                 0.3000000
40      Zeta Tau Alpha                 0.2500000
```

Comment: Welcome to stack community. Could you please make your data replicable (highlight the data and click on the { } icon. Then, show us what you would like to see in the solution and what you've tried.

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126326/how-to-quickly-form-groups-quartiles-deciles-etc-by-ordering-columns-in-a