# split dataframe in R by row

Tags: r

I have a long dataframe like this:

```
  Row  Conc   group
  1     2.5    A
  2     3.0    A
  3     4.6    B
  4     5.0    B
  5     3.2    C
  6     4.2    C
  7     5.3    D
  8     3.4    D
```

...

The actual data have hundreds of row.  I would like to split A to C, and D. I looked up the web and found several solutions but not applicable to my case.

[How to split a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302356/r-language-how-to-split-a-data-frame)

For example:
     Case 1:

```
x = data.frame(num = 1:26, let = letters, LET = LETTERS)
set.seed(10)
split(x, sample(rep(1:2, 13)))
```

I don't want to split by arbitrary number

Case 2: Split by level/factor

```
data2 <- data[data$sum_points == 2500, ]
```

I don't want to split by a single factor either.  Sometimes I want to combine many levels together.

Case 3: select by row number

```
newdf <- mydf[1:3,]
```

The actual data have hundreds of rows. I don't know the row number.  I just know the level I would like to split at.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you want two data frames, where one has `(A,B,C)` in it and one has just `D`. In that case you could do

```
Data1 <- subset(Data, group %in% c("A","B","C"))
Data2 <- subset(Data, group=="D")
```

Correct me if you were asking something different

Comment: I think maybe `split(dat,dat$group == 'D')` is sufficient.

Comment: I think maybe it's the same thing.

Comment: It (sort of) achieves the same result, but is more idiomatic, only takes one line, and conveniently returns both pieces in a single data structure. In general, one should prefer using `split`.

Comment: It returns a list of two data frames which have to be called using ` data$`FALSE` ` instead of calling data frame elements directly. It's further complicated if you want to create more than two splits. So it depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 9):

For those who end up here through internet search engines time after time, the answer to the question in the title is:

```
x <- data.frame(num = 1:26, let = letters, LET = LETTERS)

split(x, sort(as.numeric(rownames(x))))
```

Assuming that your data frame has numerically ordered row names. Also `split(x, rownames(x))` works, but the result is rearranged.

Comment: How would one go about storing each of these though? Like if I want a data frame that is `A` then `B` and so on.

Comment: @Hercislife Use `lapply()` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the `recode()` function from the "car" package.

```
# Load the library and make up some sample data
library(car)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Row = 1:100,
                  Conc = runif(100, 0, 10),
                  group = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, replace = TRUE))
```

Currently, `dat$group` contains the upper case letters A to J. Imagine we wanted the following four groups:

- "one" = A, B, C
- "two" = D, E, J
- "three" = F, I
- "four" = G, H

Now, use `recode()` (note the semicolon and the nested quotes).

```
recodes <- recode(dat$group, 
                 'c("A", "B", "C") = "one"; 
                  c("D", "E", "J") = "two"; 
                  c("F", "I") = "three"; 
                  c("G", "H") = "four"')
split(dat, recodes)
```

Comment: You don't really need the car package for this if you are comfortable working with the levels directly it only save a marginal amount of typing from `levels(dat$group)[levels(dat$group) %in% c("A","B","C")] <- "one"` for example.

Answer (score 0):

With base R, we can input the factor that we want to split on.

```
split(df, df$group == "D")
```

**Output**

```
$`FALSE`
  Row Conc group
1   1  2.5     A
2   2  3.0     A
3   3  4.6     B
4   4  5.0     B
5   5  3.2     C
6   6  4.2     C

$`TRUE`
  Row Conc group
7   7  5.3     D
8   8  3.4     D
```

If you wanted to split on multiple letters, then we could:

```
split(df, df$group %in% c("A", "D"))
```

Another option is to use `group_split` from `dplyr`, but will need to make a grouping variable first for the split.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(spl = ifelse(group == "D", 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_split(spl, .keep = FALSE)
```