# There are Lists within a dataframe. I want to convert the lists to individual dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

My Data Frame looks like this:

```
list1
list2
list3
.
.
.
list30
```

Within each list are vector data.
I want each list to be a dataframe. I don't know how to do this.

---

Edit:
@Allen Cameron already answered the question.

To get dataframe with lists to each list within the dataframe becoming dataframes use:

```
list2env(df_list, globalenv())
```

where

```
df_list
```

is the original dataframe with the lists

Comment: Please use `dput` to post something a bit more specific.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to store a list within a data frame.

Comment: @MacOS it is possible to have a column of a data frame that is a list.  For example, `dplyr::nest` will put a list of data frames as a column of a data frame.

Comment: @MichaelDewar You are right. But this is a different case because his example seems to imply that one entry (row, column) in a data frame can be list. Which is not possible. I'm unsure what he really wants/deals with exactly.

Comment: @MacOS that's not true either. Each entry in the column can be a list.

Comment: @AllanCameron I just tried to save a list in a data frame, and it does not work. Can you please provide a short code snippet? Thank you.

Comment: @MacOS see my answer for a reprex

Comment: @AllanCameron I was clearly wrong. Thank you for the example.

Comment: I want to split up dataframe. Each list I want as a new dataframe. something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125846/split-dataframe-in-r-by-row , but for each list instead of (a,b,c) in one dataframe and (d) in the other dataframe. I want nth number of splits in the dataframe depending on the number of lists. Thanks. Sorry I couldn't explain better earlier.

Comment: @BrianD Please post the output of `dput(head(df))` where `df` should be replaced by the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we have a data frame like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3)
df$b <- lapply(1:3, function(x) list(sample(3)))
df
#>   a       b
#> 1 1 1, 2, 3
#> 2 2 3, 1, 2
#> 3 3 2, 3, 1
```

Here we can see that column `b` is a list of lists:

```r
class(df$b)
#> [1] "list"

class(df$b[1])
#> [1] "list"
```

If we want to make each list in each row of column b a data frame, we can do:

```r
df_list <- setNames(lapply(df$b, function(x) data.frame(var = x[[1]])), 
                    c("df1", "df2", "df3"))
```

This gives us a list of data frames, each with its own name:

```
df_list
#> $df1
#>   var
#> 1   1
#> 2   2
#> 3   3
#> 
#> $df2
#>   var
#> 1   3
#> 2   1
#> 3   2
#> 
#> $df3
#>   var
#> 1   2
#> 2   3
#> 3   1
```

If we want, we can extract these into the global workspace like this:

```
list2env(df_list, globalenv())
```

So now we have

```r
df1
#>   var
#> 1   2
#> 2   3
#> 3   1

df2
#>   var
#> 1   1
#> 2   2
#> 3   3

df3
#>   var
#> 1   3
#> 2   1
#> 3   2
```

Personally, for most uses I would keep the data frames in `df_list` to avoid polluting the global workspace and make it easier to iterate through the data frames.

Comment: list2env(df_list, globalenv()), where df_list is the original dataframe with the lists. Thank you, that's all I wanted to know. This would be useful to anyone who wants to know it.

Comment: @BrianD you're welcome. If this answer has helped please consider marking it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post code, slackoverflow won't allow it.

[I have 37 lists in dataframe 'file contents'. I want each list to be an induvidual dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5fDP.png)

Comment: You already have a list of data frames.  If you want to access them, you can try `file_contents[[7]]` to access the 7th one, for example. Was @Allen Cameron's answer not what you were looking for?