# Splitting data.frame based on column conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I'm looking for built-in R functions to split a `data.frame` into a list of data.frames based on conditions on the column values.

To illustrate with an example, consider the `data.frame` below:

```
date         var_1       var_2        
date_1       a           b            
date_1       b           a            
date_2       c           b            
date_2       b           c            
date_2       a           b            
date_2       b           a
```

The specific grouping conditions are:

`var_1 %in% var_2 & var_2 %in% var_1 & date == date_x`,

where `date_x` runs through the unique values of `date`. These conditions define the three groups:

```
date         var_1       var_2        
date_1       a           b            
date_1       b           a
```

```
date         var_1       var_2        
date_2       c           b            
date_2       b           c
```

```
date         var_1       var_2        
date_2       a           b            
date_2       b           a
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [split dataframe in R by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125846/split-dataframe-in-r-by-row)

Comment: `split(data, ~date)` ?

Comment: I can't make sense of what you mean. If you had a row `date_1     a     c`  what would the groups look like?

Comment: You're right, splitting simply by date in the original example does the trick. My example was not constructed correctly, so I edited the values to not give the correct groups based only on date.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, you can `sort` `var_1` and `var_2` `rowwise`, and `split` for equal `date` and `sorted` values.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sorted = list(sort(c(var_1, var_2)))) %>% 
  group_by(date, sorted) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map(~ select(.x, -sorted))
```

output

```r
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  date   var_1 var_2
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 date_1 a     b    
2 date_1 b     a    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  date   var_1 var_2
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 date_2 a     b    
2 date_2 b     a    

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  date   var_1 var_2
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 date_2 c     b    
2 date_2 b     c
```