# Apply same filter on multiple dataframes across different environments

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have some large `sf` objects that live in the Global Environment while the main code is executed. This main code calls `create_foo_map` functions that use filtered versions of the large `sf` objects and also import/create their own smaller `sf` objects to which the same filters should be applied. Ideally, the filter would work inside `create_foo_map` and leave the large objects in the global environment untouched.

[This post on `list2env`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302356/how-to-split-a-data-frame) led me to something like the following, which applies the same filter across various datasets but would need a lot of tweaking to work across two environments.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(100)


volcano1 <- sample_frac(faithful, 0.25)
volcano2 <- sample_frac(faithful, 0.25)
volcano3 <- sample_frac(faithful, 0.25)
volcano4 <- sample_frac(faithful, 0.25)



exclude <- function(df) {

  df <- get(df)

  df %>% 
    filter(waiting > 90)

}


basic_obj <- ls(pattern = "volcano")

mod_obj <- map(basic_obj, exclude) 

names(mod_obj) <- basic_obj

list2env(mod_obj, envir = environment())
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

So, I have two (sets of) questions:

1) Is this the simplest method to apply the same filter across several dataframes? I was thinking of `purrr::modify` but didn't end up with anything simpler.

2) Can this (or an alternative method) be expanded to dataframes both inside a function and in the global environment (or another env)? How?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: To be honest I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. I would keep all objects in a `list`, and then uniformly operate on these objects using `purrr::map`/`lapply`. Why do you need to do `list2env`? I would import all datasets and store resulting objects in a `list` directly, e.g. using something along the lines of `lst <- map(list_of_filenames, read_csv)`.

Comment: @Maurits thanks! I probably shouldn't have mentioned imports as that's not the point. I was trying to generalise from my specific example. I have some large SF objects that live in the Global Environment while the main code is executed. This main code calls map-making functions that use filtered versions of the large SF objects and also create their own smaller objects to which the same filters should be applied.