# How can I make a new data set from names of rows?

Tags: r, for-loop, filter

My dataset is in a long format that has the names of countries, years and values in the columns.

I want new dataset for each country and for each year, I can do it individually but repeating that 195 is not great so I want to do it using "for"

This works for and individual country

```
Mali = filter(datosUnicef , CountryName == "Mali")
```

But this doesn't seems to work

```
for (i in datosUnicef$CountryName) {
   i = filter(datosUnicef , CountryName == i)
}
```

how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the intention is to create multiple datasets, use `group_split` to split the data into `list` of `data.frame`s

```
library(dplyr)
lst1 <- datosUnicef %>%
            group_split(CountryName)
```

and extract the data from `list` with `[[` or `$`

NOTE:  It is better not to create multiple objects in the global environment.  Instead, create a `list`

---

Regarding the issue in OP's code, it is assigning to letter `i` in each iteration, so it gets updated.  Instead, an option would be `assign` (not recommended though)

```
for(i in unique(datosUnicef$CountryName)) {
      assign(i, filter(datosUnicef, CountryName == i))
   }
```

Comment: Without going into further discussion: how is this question not a dupe of [How to split a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302356/how-to-split-a-data-frame)

Comment: @markus I think the OP is concerned more about his `for` loop failure though `split` is an option.  But, if the OP's intention is to understand the reason behind the failure of his/her code, it is not a dupe

Comment: Well, fair enough.