# splitting the data set base on a specific start in the cell

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataset like

```
df <- data.frame(year.id = c("2011.01","2011.02","2011.03",
                         "2013.01","2013.02","2013.03",
                         "2015.01","2015.02","2015.03"),
             values =c(20,25,30,
                       40,50,60,
                       70,80,90))
```

and I want to split this dataset if yearid starts with 2011/2013/2015 and what to get three datasets

```
 ##first df 
year.id values
2011.01     20
2011.02     25
2011.03     30
##second df 
2013.01     40
2013.02     50
2013.03     60
##third df
2015.01     70
2015.02     80
2015.03     90
```

many thanks in advance,

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302356/how-to-split-a-data-frame

Comment: try `split(df,gsub("(.*)\\..*","\\1",df$year.id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same data as shown you can extract the year part using regex and then use `split`

```
split(df, sub("\\..*", "", df$year.id))

#$`2011`
#  year.id values
#1 2011.01     20
#2 2011.02     25
#3 2011.03     30

#$`2013`
#  year.id values
#4 2013.01     40
#5 2013.02     50
#6 2013.03     60

#$`2015`
#  year.id values
#7 2015.01     70
#8 2015.02     80
#9 2015.03     90
```

If there are other years in the data and you want to extract only the ones mentioned

```
df$year <- sub("\\..*", "", df$year.id)
temp <- subset(df,  year %in% c(2011, 2013, 2015))
split(temp, temp$year)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df2011=df[grepl("2011",df$year.id),]
df2013=df[grepl("2013",df$year.id),]
df2015=df[grepl("2015",df$year.id),]
```