# Split dataframe in multiple then apply a function, using for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to split a dataframe into multiple dataframes under the criteria that the data is filtered/subsetted by a shared value of the column `plot`. Previously, I used `dplyr` to subset the data based on some conditions, and select the data I would like to keep (see below). Instead of copy and pasting the same code X amount of times, I want to use a `for` loop to reduce the line of code.

```
data.p1 <- data %>% 
  filter(plot==1) %>%
  select(posX, posY, germ_bin)

data.p2 <- data %>% 
  filter(plot==2) %>%
  select(posX, posY, germ_bin)
```

After splitting the original dataframe `data` into separate dataframes (e.g `data.p1`), I would to apply a function such as `raster`. Is it possible to also include this function in the for loop?

Comment: Try `out <- split(subset(data, select = c(posX, posY, germ_bin), data$plot)`. Then do `lapply(out, raster)` (or use `by()` instead of `lapply(split(...` BTW: `data` and `plot` are function names in R.

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to split a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302356/how-to-split-a-data-frame)

Comment: Based on your recommendation + the other thread, I have the following: 
`out <- subset(data, select = c(posX, posY, germ_bin, flwr_bin, seed_bin, plot))` followed by `out <- split(out, f=as.factor(out$plot))` and `lapply(out, rasterFromXYZ)`. Note I separated the original `split` line into 2 because subsetting the data without plot initially made it difficult to apply the `split` function.

I want to apply another function called `focalWeight` to each df in the list, but I need to specify the df being applied. How would I achieve this with `lapply` or its family of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset your data and apply the `raster` function within the same `lapply`. The only thing you have to be careful is that if you are loading `dplyr` and `raster` packages at the same time, you will have problems with the `select` function, as each package has its own `select` function. Probably, the best approach is to load just one package (for example `dplyr`) and use the `::` notation to refer to functions of the other package (for example `raster`) like `raster::raster`. Here is an example applying the `rasterFromXYZ` to each subsetted data.

```
library(dplyr)
data_list<-lapply(unique(data$plot), function(i){
  raster::rasterFromXYZ(data %>%
    filter(plot==i) %>%
    select(posX, posY, germ_bin))
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am learning more than I expected! For ex, the `::` notation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be helpful for what you are trying to achieve:

```r
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(
  plot = sample(4, 5, replace = T),
  posX = sample(100, 5, replace = T), 
  posY = sample(100, 5, replace = T), 
  germ_bin = sample(100, 5, replace = T)
)
#   plot posX posY germ_bin
# 1    3   55   88       74
# 2    1   72   15       34
# 3    2   54   15       24
# 4    4   39   42       13
# 5    4   83   71       95
list_of_df <- list()
for (i in 1:max(data$plot)) {
  list_of_df[[i]] <- data %>% 
    dplyr::filter(plot==i) %>%
    dplyr::select(posX, posY, germ_bin)
  # possibly another functions here
}
# [[1]]
#   posX posY germ_bin
# 1   72   15       34
# [[2]]
#   posX posY germ_bin
# 1   54   15       24
# [[3]]
#   posX posY germ_bin
# 1   55   88       74
# [[4]]
#   posX posY germ_bin
# 1   39   42       13
# 2   83   71       95
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not correctly select for the 3 variables `posX` `posY` and `germ_bin` and outputs a double vector instead of multiple dfs.

Comment: That is correct, it was because of using single brackets while assigning new data frames into list elements. I updated the example with a small example that you can take a look.