# Dividing data into groups by attribute

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
    Year Period  Power  Span Length Weight Speed Range
1     14      1   82.0 12.80   7.60   1070   105   400
2     14      2   82.0 11.00   9.00    830   145   402
3     14      1  223.6 17.90  10.35   2200   135   500
4     15      2  164.0 14.50   9.80   1946   138   500
5     15      3  119.0 12.90   7.90   1190   140   400
6     15      3   74.5  7.50   6.30    653   177   350
7     15      1   74.5 11.13   8.28    930   113   402
8     16      2  279.5 14.30   9.40   1575   230   700
9     16      1   82.0  7.80   6.70    676   175   525
10    16      3   67.0 11.00   8.30    920   106   300
```

How can I use R to divide this data into the three groups represented by `Period`?

Comment: `split(df, df$Period)` ?

Comment: hi.. you want data as separate data frame ?if it is so refer example this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302356/how-to-split-a-data-frame#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20split,()%20from%20the%20plyr%20package.&text=Now%2C%20x%20is%20an%20array,level%20of%20the%20splitting%20variable.

Comment: @TusharLad I want to show plots separately for the three periods.

Comment: @RonakShah I think this might work. Is there a way to separate the three data frames? Do I just access them individually as elements of a list?

Comment: @ThePointer Try `?list2env`.

Comment: You can use `list2env`, see linked answer.

Comment: @jay.sf This produces an "environment"; what do I do with this?

Comment: @ThePointer You need argument `list2env(.,envir=.GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: @the Pointer please make your question modified or share what you have tried so far will be happy to help.

Comment: @TusharLad I can do the plots on my own. I just wanted to know how to split the data.

Comment: @jay.sf I still get an "environment"; except, now it's `environment: R_GlobalEnv`. I'm not sure what to do with this.

Comment: @ThePointer make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and ask a new question.